# realign field from right to left?

Tags: awk

I'm making an awk program for inserting delimiters and deleting whitespace.
One of my fields is problematic, it's aligned to the right.
How do I take everything in a field and align it to the left of the field?

```
ex: fields delimited by %

12340987%    29873%giberish   %
11234513%  34.122-%gibergiber %
to:
12340987%29873    %giberish   %
11234513%34.122-  %gibergiber %
```

Comment: Please, add a sample input, and a sample output, demonstrating what you want to achieve.

Comment: Is it always going to be 3 fields (last blank) like that or an arbitrary number? A fixed width or whatever it happens to be?

Comment: I'm always delimiting the fields by a fixed width, and the screwed up field is always the second field, but the amount of whitespace from the end of the first field to the first char of the second field varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="%"}{sub(/^ */,"",$2);$2=sprintf("%-8s",$2); print}'
```

You can change the `8` to control the width of the field.

Comment: Having a problem with the int() part I want to print periods and dashes also. This cuts off 7.12 at 7.

Comment: What problem? Works for me with both gnu and mac awks

Comment: Ah, you have floats too. You should probably add that to the sample input

Comment: %          24.54-% into %24           % I want %24.54-        %

Comment: OK, I've updated for this new case, it should work with any input.

Comment: This does solve my problem, but it wouldn't if I were doing the same thing to a field containing addresses, because it would delete the spaces between "76 Cherrywood Drive". Is there a simple way trim a field of only leading whitespace?

Comment: Yes, you just need to change the substitution slightly - updated.